# Jquery Ajax Send data to endpoint with POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to send som data to an endpoint. In the documentation it is written as product[xx][amount] where xx is an id.
I can't figure out what the syntax should be.

```
var postData = {
            product:153,
            amount:1
          };
```

or

```
var postData = {
            product[153][1]
          };
```

maybe. But none of them works.

The entire code is

```
var postData = {
            product:153,
            amount:1
          };

          $.ajax({
            url: '/actions/cart/add',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: postData,
            success: function(data) {
              console.log('Data has been posted');
              console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
              console.log(err.statusText);
            }
          });
```

The response tells me that amount is missing.

Comment: can you elaborate more this line `documentation it is written ...` ? Also, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r4cp8Lw5/).

Comment: Yes but unfortunately it is in Danish. https://help.hostedshop.dk/ajax-i-action-filer/

Something specific you need to know?

Comment: Did you tried that above fiddle ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the link. I tried it now at I get 5 written in console log. But if I set postData = product I still get the error that amount is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var postData = {
    product: {
        153: 1
    }
};
```

Comment: Data is posted, but still the error is that there is no amount.